# The heat equation on the intervall [0,1] with Robin Boundary

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have the heat equation on the invervall $[0,1]$, therefore I define

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
```

and I define my initial data which can be boring, since the BC are not,

```
init= u[x,0]==0.5
```

Now I'd like to impose Robin-Boundary Condtions of the form

$$ u'(0,t)=1-u(0,t)\\
-u'(1,t)=1-u(1,t) $$

However while scrolling through the help-parts of DSolve and NDSolve, I found `NeumannValue` however I am totally honest, I have no Idea what is going on and how I impose those BCs on my PDE. However, I am not completely new to Mathematica, just to solving PDEs with it, I can manage doing stuff like Dirichlet on the intervall $[0,1]$

```
NDSolve[{
      D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
      u[0, x] == Sin[Pi x]+0.5,
      u[t, 0] == 0.5,
      u[t, 1] == 0.5},
     u, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 1}]
    Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. %], {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Something like this, `{D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] == 
  NeumannValue[1 - u[t, x], x == 0] - 
   NeumannValue[1 - u[t, x], x == 1], u[0, x] == Sin[Pi x] + 0.5}` but make sure that your initial and boundary conditions are consistent.

Comment: Should it not read: `NeumannValue[-1 + u[t, x], x == 1]`

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment:

A consistent initial condition is `u[0,t]==Sin[Pi x]+1-Pi`

```
{Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] - (1 - u[t, 0]), 
-Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1] - (1 - u[t, 1])} /.u -> Function[{t, x},  Sin[Pi x] + 1 - Pi]
(* {0,0}*)
```

But the solution proposed by @user21

```
U = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
D[u[t, x], x, x] + NeumannValue[ -(1 - u[t, x]),x == 0] - 
NeumannValue[ (1 - u[t, x]), x == 1], 
u[0, x] == Sin[Pi x] + 1 - Pi }, u, {t, 0, 3},{x, 0, 1}]
```

unfortunately doesn't fullfill the Robin boundary conditions for all `t`

```
Plot[{Derivative[0, 1][U][t, 0] - (1 - U[t, 0]), -Derivative[0, 1][U][t, 1] - (1 -U[t, 1])}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Robin bc[t]"]
```

[image]